# Group action on $\mathbb R^2$: are my thoughts correct?

Tags: group-actions

Let $G=\mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z$ for $n > 2$ and let $G$ act on $\mathbb R^2$ linearly and effectively. Let $T_g (v)$ denote the element $gv$ where $v \in \mathbb R^2$. Assume that $\det T_g > 0$ and that $\langle T_g v, T_g v'\rangle = \langle v,v'\rangle$.

I want to show that there exists exactly one $g \in G$ such that $T_g$ is a rotation of angle ${2 \pi \over n}$.

> Please could someone tell me if what I did is correct?

That $G$ acts linearly means that $T_g$ is a linear transformation, that is, a $2 \times 2$ matrix. (use that matrices and linear transformations are in bijection without proof)

That $\langle T_g v, T_g v'\rangle = \langle v,v'\rangle$ therefore means that $T_g$ is a linear isometry of $\mathbb R^2$. Hence its determinant is either $1$ or $-1$ but since we have $\det T_g>0$ it must be $1$. (use that linear isometries have determinant $\pm 1$ without proof)

Also without proof I want to use that linear isometries of $\mathbb R^n$ are either rotations or reflections but since $\det =1$ this one is a rotation.

**Edit**

To simplify notation we use the complex representation of the problem: $\mathbb R^2 = \mathbb C^2$ and rotation by $\theta$ is multiplication by $e^{i\theta}$.

We have $T_1^n = I$ (because the action is effective) that is, $(e^{in \theta}) = 1 = e^{2 \pi i k}$. Taking the logarithm we get $\theta = {2\pi k\over n}$ where $k \in \mathbb Z$.

Therefore $T_1$ is rotation by $\theta = {2\pi k \over n}$. Since $1$ generates $G$, $T_1$ must generate the group $T_1, \dots, T_n$.

> Do I have to prove this claim? (by providing a group isomorphism from $G$ to $\{T_k\}_k$)

Now I have two things left to do: I have to argue that $k$ has to be coprime to $n$ (otherwise it wouldn't generate the group) and finally I somehow need to argue why $k=1$ (at the moment I really don't see how this is possible)

$\color{grey}{\text{
Finally, consider $1 \in \mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z$. Note that $1^n = id$. Hence $T_1^n = I$. This is true for the matrix that is rotation by ${2\pi / n}$. Hence there exists $g\in G$ such that $T_g$ is rotation by ${2\pi / n}$.}}$

$\color{grey}{\text{
Now assume $T_g$ was another rotation such that $T_g^n=I$. It's not clear how to argue with more mathematical rigor but it is clear}}$
$\color{grey}{\text{ that the only rotations that achieve the identity when applied $n$ times are rotations by ${2\pi \over n}+k 2\pi$. }}$

Comment: Please make titles informative. You're not filming a movie. Well, maybe you are, but that's irrelevant to the post.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Sure, no problem, what would be a better title?

Comment: It never occurred to me.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in your conclusion. Let me denote by $k(\theta)$ the $2 \times 2$ rotation matrix with rotation angle $\theta$. Your argument beginning with "Finally, consider $1$ ..." isn't really complete. Essentially what you've shown there is that $T_1 \in \{k(2\pi m/n) : m = 0,1,\ldots,n\}$ (although you should probably justify why these are the only rotation matrices with order dividing $n$), and it very well may be the case that $T_1 = k(2\pi m/n)$ where $m \neq 1$.

So what can you do to show that $T_g = k(2\pi/n)$ for some $g$? My hint would be to look at the other information about the group action you haven't used yet, *i.e.*, that it's effective. This will also be useful (critical, really) in showing that $g \in G$ with $T_g = k(2\pi/n)$ is unique. I've provided a bigger hint in a spoiler tag below, but try doing this yourself before looking at it.

> Show that $T_1 = k(2\pi m/n)$ where $m$ and $n$ are coprime. Then use effectiveness and the fact that $1$ generates the group to get that $T_g = k(2\pi/n)$ for some $g$.

---

Edit (in response to your new argument and comments):

> To simplify notation we use the complex representation of the problem: $\mathbb R^2 = \mathbb C^2$ and rotation by $\theta$ is multiplication by $e^{i\theta}$.

A few points:

- Minor correction here (it's probably just a typo), but $\mathbb R^2 \cong \mathbb C$ as real vector spaces, not $\mathbb C^2$.
- Although your intuition that you may identify $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb C$ is correct, in any formal setting [that is, one outside the realm of math.SE `:)`] there are definitely some things to justify about why it's ok to make this substitution here. First, what is the $\mathbb R$-linear isomorphism $\varphi: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb C$ you're using? Second, and more significantly here, the map $\varphi$ enables us to identify these two vectors spaces, but we're concerned with the linear transformations on these spaces, not the spaces themselves. How does $\varphi$ affect linear transformations? Moreover, given a linear transformation $T: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$, the map $\varphi$ should identify $T$ with some other transformation $T': \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$. Given $T$, what does $T'$ look like? (A common notation for this new linear map is $\varphi^*(T)$.) For instance, if I begin with the rotation-by-$\theta$ mapping $T = k(\theta)$, what does $\varphi$ "send" $k(\theta)$ to? interact with the group action we're looking at? This is totally possible (and a cool way to rethink the problem), but I thought I'd provide some food for thought. `:)`
- To avoid going through the work of identifying $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb C$, you can use a more elementary argument to conclude that $T^n = I$ for $T$ a rotation matrix implies $T = k(2\pi m/n)$ for some $m$. Write $T = k(\theta)$ for some $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$. Then $T^n = k(n\theta) = I$, and the only real numbers $\psi$ (think $\psi = n\theta$) for which $k(\psi) = I$ are $\psi = 2\pi m$ for $m \in \mathbb Z$ (show this by explicitly writing out the components of $k(\psi)$ if this is unclear to you). Hence $n\theta = 2\pi m$ for some integer $m$, and therefore $\theta = 2\pi m/n$. The assumption that $0 \leq \theta < 2\pi$ then implies that $m \in \{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$.

Here is a quick way to reach the desired conclusion, given what we already know. From this, it follows that $T_1 = k(2\pi m/n)$ for some $m \in \{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$. In fact, since $n\cdot g = \text{Id}$ for all $g \in G = \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$, the same argument (beginning with the observation $T_g^n = I$) implies that for each $g \in G$ there exists $m_g \in \{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$ such that $T_g = k(2\pi m_g/n)$. Since the action is effective, we know that $T_g \neq T_{g'}$ for all $g,g'\in G$. Thus $\{T_g : g \in G\} \subseteq \{k(2\pi m/n) : m = 0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$ and

$$
\#\{T_g : g \in G\} = \# G = n = \#\{k(2\pi m/n) : m = 0,1,\ldots,n-1\},
$$

from which it follows that $\{T_g : g \in G\} = \{k(2\pi m/n) : m = 0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$. Therefore $T_g = k(2\pi/n)$ must hold for some $g \in G$.

Comment: Thank you, I see the mistake. From $T_1^n = I$ I only get that $T_1$ is rotation by ${2\pi \over n} + k2\pi$. (It's not clear to me why you have $km2\pi /n$). So I have to use that the action is effective to show that $k=0$ basically...

Comment: I don't understand this. The rotation by $2\pi / n$ is not distinguishable from the rotation by $2\pi / n + k 2 \pi$. Once I have $T_1^n = I$ it should immediately follow that $T_1$ is rotation by $2 \pi / n + k 2 \pi$ but since for multiples of $k$ they are equivalent I am done. What am I missing?

Comment: I added all my additional thoughts to the question.

Comment: @user174981: I tacked an edit onto my original answer, in response to your revisions.